# Executing MySql stored procedures from C# app using MysqlConnector is slow?

Tags: c#, mysql

I have a stored procedure in MySql that inserts 10.000 registers. When I execute it from MySql command line the query takes 1sec but when I do it from the .NET C# application I wrote, it takes around 8sec.

Do you have a hint about what its going on?

- The MySql Server version is 5.5.16
- And also for doing the test I've tried some version of the Mysql .Net connector but I get the same results.
- I've executed the console app on two different computers 32 and 64 bits.

C# code:

```
    string connStr = "ommited";

    MySqlConnection conn = MySqlConnection(connStr);

    MySqlCommand micomando = new MySqlCommand("CALL my_procedure();", conn);
    micomando.Connection.Open();
    micomando.ExecuteNonQuery();

    ArrayList recordSet = new ArrayList();

    conn.Close();
```

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Are you sure you are only executing the call 10.000 times and not some extra code like connection open/close? These operations are really slow.

Comment: Im sure. I've extracted the connection opening/closing timming out of my monitoring because it was the first thing I suspected about

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Comapare `ExecuteNonQuery` time and MySql command line execution time.

```
Stopwatch sw = Stopwatch.StartNew();
micomando.ExecuteNonQuery();
sw.Stop();
Console.WriteLine("Time taken: {0}ms", sw.Elapsed.TotalMilliseconds);
```

Query execution is not the only task done by the .net program.

Comment: I dindt specified in the first post but I'Ve got the timings like you said!